# installing tensorflow-model-analysis on Google Cloud datalab

Tags: tensorflow-model-analysis

I am running the followoing command:

```
!pip install tesnorflow-model-analysis
```

and receiving the following error:

```
Collecting tesnorflow-model-analysis
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tesnorflow-model-analysis (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tesnorflow-model-analysis
```

The environment on Google Cloud Datalab is the following:

```
!python -V
Python 2.7.15 :: Anaconda, Inc.

!pip show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.11.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc......
```

1st question: what are the requirements to make this library working?

One I have it install, I would like to have it running on Google Cloud Datalab.

There are commands to have it available on jupyter notebooks.

```
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
jupyter nbextension install --py --symlink tensorflow_model_analysis
jupyter nbextension enable --py tensorflow_model_analysis
```

2nd question: what are the equivalents on Google Datalab Notebook?

Many thanks,
eilalan

Answer (score 2):

> 1st question: what are the requirements to make this library working?

It looks like there is a typo in the package name; try `!pip install tensorflow-model-analysis` instead.

Comment: the installation went fine. the import is failing. !pip show tensorflow-model-analysis output is:                         
Name: tensorflow-model-analysis
Version: 0.11.0
Summary: A library for analyzing TensorFlow models
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/model_analysis
Author: Google LLC
Author-email: tensorflow-extended-dev@googlegroups.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: numpy, ipywidgets, jupyter, apache-beam, tensorflow-transform, protobuf, six

Comment: Can you describe what steps you are taking and how the failure manifests?

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for your response. I was able to import the module and run the commands by updating the packages that are installed on the datalab environment. My current challenge is rendering the tfma plots. I am currently running the Chicago taxi example. Please see this location on my google drive for the code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Inm8qvcOM2cc2f1G-p65aLHHNNVX6_i4/view?usp=sharing  tfma.view.render_slicing_metrics(tfma_result_1, slicing_column='trip_start_hour'). Many thanks for any reference, eilalan

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth, I also do my work on GCP with datalab.  I was pleasantly surprised that I could get my estimator based code working in a jupyterlab notebook. On datalab I use python3.  On jupyterlab I use python2 and once I got the google cloud sdk 236.0.0 installed I could even do prediction using %%bash gcloud ml-engine --local working.